# Preserving index when slicing columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

In pandas

When I do

```
df2 = df1[['colA', 'colB]]
```

I have a new dataframe `df2` but now the index from `df1` is lost.

How could I keep the index of `df1` to `df2`?

Many thanks

Comment: can you please share a minimum working example? The line you wrote should work.

Comment: `but now the index from df1 is lost` .... are you sure? Index should be the same as `df1`